# Is there a way to continue executing a javascript function from the same point after a page postback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, automation, screen-scraping

I have to work on an old system here at work where there are long lists of data that i have to mark for deletion, and since this application is really old (.net 1.1 i guess) and nobody has the source, I have to do it manually by using javascript to try to automate the application  interface.

Heres the process i want to automate using a bookmarklet:

1. on the website page, search for all the checkbox elements and set them to checked
2. go to the end of the page, click on the submit button and wait for the postback
3. click on the "next page" link on the pagination section at the bottom of the list
4. wait for the new page to load
5. repeat until there is no more "next page button".

The html is very well structured, so finding the controls to click, etc., is really not the problem, what I cannot figure out how to do is continue executing the javacript function after the page postback is done.

Does anyone know how to do something like this?

pseudocode of what i got so far, besides the WaiForThePostbackToComplete i have figured it out all the rest:

```
while($('#nextPageLink').length) {
  var checkboxes = getCheckboxes();
  checkboxes.each(click());
  var submitbutton = getSubmitButton();
  document.location = submitbutton.attr('href');

  // im stuck here, after the postback the function stops
  WaiForThePostbackToComplete();


  var nextpage = getNextPageLink();
  document.location = nextpagelink.attr('href');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really restart back from a line. I don't know of any programming language that would let you start execution from a line if you didn't know which one.

What you need to do here is maintain state of what you last executed.

The simplest option would be to use a javascript cookie to keep this state.

```
document.cookie = 'timesRum=1; expires=Wed, 24 Jul 2013 02:47:11 UTC; path=/'
```

You can refer this tutorial, that will give you a few [helper functions to work with cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

Comment: I tried using that, but after the first page postback, both the cookie and my script disappear! If I could find a way to keep the script alive after the postback, using cookies would solve my problem indeed.

Comment: Did you execute the bookmarklet after the postback? cookies don't vanish off. Your script is not on the page so it will vanish, you will have to call it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
<% if(IsPostBack)
{%>
var nextpage = getNextPageLink();
document.location = nextpagelink.attr('href');
<%}%>
```

Comment: I dont have access to the souce :(